# How can I create Daemon in LaunchAgents from macOS APP?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, daemon

I want to create Daemon (Plist in ~/Library/LaunchAgents/) from my macOS application.

```
import Foundation

func shell(_ command: String) -> String {
    let task = Process()
    let pipe = Pipe()

    task.standardOutput = pipe
    task.arguments = ["-c", command]
    task.launchPath = "/bin/bash"
    task.launch()

    let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    let output = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!

    return output
}

// Example usage:
shell("ls -la")
```

I know using this I can create a daemon but at this location

```
 ~/Library/LaunchAgents/
```

I am not able to create due to permission issues.  `Operation not permitted`

But using **terminal** I am able to Create Plist inside
`~/Library/LaunchAgents/`

Comment: Does your app have full disk access permission ?

Comment: @anki how should I get that?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/339862/ls-operation-not-permitted-mojave-security/345142#345142